# Vowpal Wabbit model works badly on multiclass classification of images using pixel RGB values

Tags: image, machine-learning, classification, logistic-regression, vowpalwabbit

I am using Vowpal Wabbit to classify multi class images. My data set is similar to http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html , consisting of 3000 training samples and 500 testing samples. The features are RGB values of 32*32 images. I used Vowpal Wabbit Logistic loss function to train the model with 100 iterations. During the training process the average loss is below 0.02 (I assume this number is pretty good right?). Then I predict the labels of the training set with the output model, and fount that the predictions are very bad. Nearly all of them are of category six. I really don't know what happened, because it seems to me that during training process the predictions mostly correct, but after I predict with the model they suddenly become all 6.

Here is a sample line of feature.

> 1 | 211 174 171 165 161 161 162 163 163 163 163 163 163 163 163 163
>   162 161 162 163 163 163 163 164 165 167 168 167 168 163 160 187 153
>   102 96 90 89 90 91 92 92 92 92 92 92 92 92 92 92 92 91 90 90 90 90 91
>   92 94 95 96 99 97 98 127 111 71 71 64 66 68 69 69 69 69 69 69 70 70 69
>   69 70 71 71 69 68 68 68 68 70 72 73 75 78 78 81 96 111 69 68 61 64 67
>   67 67 67 67 67 67 68 67 67 66 67 68 69 68 68 67 66 66 67 69 69 69 71
>   70 77 89 116 74 76 71 72 74 74 72 73 74 74 74 74 74 74 74 72 72 74 76
>   76 75 74 74 74 73 73 72 73 74 85 92 123 83 86 83 82 83 83 82 83 83 82
>   82 82 82 82 82 81 80 82 85 85 84 83 83 83 85 85 85 85 86 94 95 127 92
>   96 93 93 92 91 91 91 91 91 90 89 89 86 86 86 86 87 89 89 88 88 88 92
>   92 93 98 100 96 98 96 132 99 101 98 98 97 95 93 93 94 93 93 95 96 97
>   95 96 96 96 96 95 94 100 103 98 93 95 100 105 103 103 96 139 106 108
>   105 102 100 98 98 98 99 99 100 100 95 98 93 81 78 79 77 76 76 79 98
>   107 102 97 98 103 107 108 99 145 115 118 115 115 115 113 ......

Here is my training script:

> ./vw train.vw --oaa 6  --passes 100 --loss_function logistic -c
>   --holdout_off -f image_classification.model

Here is my predicting script (on the training data set):

> ./vw -i image_classification.model -t train.vw -p train.predict --quiet

Here is the statistics during training:

> final_regressor = image_classification.model Num weight bits = 18
>   learning rate = 0.5 initial_t = 0 power_t = 0.5 decay_learning_rate =
>   1 using cache_file = train.vw.cache ignoring text input in favor of
>   cache input num sources = 1 average  since         example
>   example  current  current  current loss     last          counter
>   weight    label  predict features
>   0.000000 0.000000            1            1.0        1        1     3073
>   0.000000 0.000000            2            2.0        1        1     3073
>   0.000000 0.000000            4            4.0        1        1     3073
>   0.000000 0.000000            8            8.0        1        1     3073
>   0.000000 0.000000           16           16.0        1        1     3073
>   0.000000 0.000000           32           32.0        1        1     3073
>   0.000000 0.000000           64           64.0        1        1     3073
>   0.000000 0.000000          128          128.0        1        1     3073
>   0.000000 0.000000          256          256.0        1        1     3073
>   0.001953 0.003906          512          512.0        2        2     3073
>   0.002930 0.003906         1024         1024.0        3        3     3073
>   0.002930 0.002930         2048         2048.0        5        5     3073
>   0.006836 0.010742         4096         4096.0        3        3     3073
>   0.012573 0.018311         8192         8192.0        5        5     3073
>   0.014465 0.016357        16384        16384.0        3        3     3073
>   0.017029 0.019592        32768        32768.0        6        6     3073
>   0.017731 0.018433        65536        65536.0        6        6     3073
>   0.017891 0.018051       131072       131072.0        5        5     3073
>   0.017975 0.018059       262144       262144.0        3        3     3073
>
> finished run number of examples per pass = 3000 passes used = 100
>   weighted example sum = 300000.000000 weighted label sum = 0.000000
>   average loss = 0.017887 total feature number = 921900000

It seems to me that it predicts perfectly during training but after I use the outputed model suddenly everything becomes of category 6. I really have no idea what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems in your approach.

1) I guess the training set contains first all images with label 1, then all examples with label 2 and so on, the last label is 6. You need to shuffle such training data if you want to use online learning (which is the default learning algorithm in VW).

2) VW uses sparse feature format. The order of features on one line is not important (unless you use --ngram). So if feature number 1 (red channel of the top left pixel) has value 211 and feature number 2 (red channel of the second pixel) has value 174, you need to use:

```
1 | 1:211 2:147 ...
```

3) To get good results in image recognition you need something better than a linear model on the raw pixel values. Unfortunately, VW has no deep learning (multi-layer neural net), no convolutional nets. You can try `--nn X` to get neural net with one hidden layer with X units (and tanh activation function), but this is just a poor substitute for [the state-of-the-art approaches to CIFAR etc](http://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/classification_datasets_results.html). You can also try other non-linear reductions available in VW (`-q`, `--cubic`, `--lrq`, `--ksvm`, `--stage_poly`). In general, I think VW is not suitable for such tasks (image recognition), unless you apply some preprocessing which generates (a lot of) features (e.g. SIFT).

4) You are overfitting.

> average loss is below 0.02 (I assume this number is pretty good right?

No. You used `--holdout_off`, so the reported loss is rather the *train* loss. It is easy to get almost zero train loss by simple memoizing all examples, i.e. overfitting. However, you want to get the *test* (or holdout) loss low.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed advice!

Comment: Also: `--oaa 6` will use 6 classes, the CIFAR data-set has 10 classes so you want `--oaa 10`  And also: `--ect N` usually performs better than `-oaa N`.